# identify what custom qgraphicsitem was clicked by a mouse click

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have an issue with identifying an id of a custom qgraphicsobject. My custom QgraphicsItem stores Id, start X,Y positions and setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable,true);  I have pushed my items into a QMap and then painted them on a QGraphicsScene. During mouse click i can get all my items using items() method. But how can I determine what Item was clicked? I can cast QGraphicsItem to my type but how I can get an Id of a clicked item? By getting the coordinates of a my graphics item?

My LightObject class

```
public:
LightObject(qreal x, qreal y, QColor color, QGraphicsEllipseItem *parent=0);
LightObject();

void drawFocusRect(QPainter *painter);

QRectF boundingRect();

int id() const;
void setId(int id);


signals:
    void setColor(const QColor&,int);

protected:
    int type() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
virtual void setGeometry(const QRectF& rect);
virtual QSizeF sizeHint(Qt::SizeHint which,
                           const QSizeF& constraint = QSizeF()) const;


public slots:


private:
    bool isSelected_;

    int id_;
    qreal xPos_;//X position on scene
    qreal yPos_;

    qreal radius = 60;

    qreal rw_;
    qreal rh_;
    QColor color_;
    QPixmap *mPixmap;
```

My CustomScene class

```
void EffectPreviewScene::paintLights(int x,int y)
{
    int offsetX = 10;
    int offsetY = 10;
    int i = 0;
    for (int xcnt=0;xcnt<x;xcnt++){
        for (int ycnt=0;ycnt<y;ycnt++){              
            QGraphicsLayoutItem *i = new QGraphicsLayoutItem(0);

            LightObject *mLight = new LightObject(offsetX,offsetY,QColor( 255, 0, 0));//graphicsobject. store coordinates
            mLight->setId(i);//?

            mLight->setX(xcnt);
            mLight->setY(ycnt);

            qDebug() << "xcnt=" << xcnt;
            qDebug() << "ycnt=" << ycnt;
            addItem(mLight); //added

            qDebug() << "offsetX=" << offsetX;

            offsetY += 40;
            qDebug() << "offsetY=" << offsetY;

            i++;
        }
    }
}

void EffectPreviewScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{   //?
    if(!event->isAccepted()) {
        testUpdate();//repaint to green
        qDebug() << "graphics scene event not accepted";
        QGraphicsItem *item;
        item = itemAt(event->pos(),QTransform()); //Get the item at the position //?

        QList<QGraphicsItem*> potentialSelections = items();//items(event->pos());

        for(auto iter = potentialSelections.begin(); iter != potentialSelections.end() ; ++iter)
                 {
                     if((*iter)->flags() & QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable)
                     {
                         item = *iter;
                     }
                 }
    qDebug () << "potentialSelections.size()="<<potentialSelections.size();
      qDebug() << "RECT=" <<item->boundingRect();//scene becomes an item

      if (item) //If there is an item at that position
      {            
          qDebug() << "found";
          qDebug() << "lights.size()"<<lights.size();
          mlight = dynamic_cast<LightObject*>(item);
         connect(mlight,&LightObject::setColor,mColorManager,ColorManager::colorChanged);
          if (mlight){
          //get x,y,id
              qDebug() << "color="<< mlight->color();
           qDebug() <<  mlight->rect();
            qDebug() << "id=" << mlight->id();
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: itemAt() should be the answer, the item is returned giving the position, but as I see in your may not be, in order to help you I need you to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for itemAt() I will provide example at pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/b6XdwR56 Here is the paste

Comment: LightObject does not inherit from QObject therefore it can not implement signals, that is, the following line does not make sense: `connect(mlight,&LightObject::setColor,mColorManager,ColorManager::colorChanged);`, Also I see that you are implementing the LightObject class incorrectly. What is the purpose of LightObject? What feature do you want to change, add, modify or delete from QGraphicsEllipseItem?